# Hover not working

Tags: jquery, hover

When I add [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) to my page, hover effect on links doesn't work. Without it, it works.

```
<script src="jquery.color.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$("a").hover(
function() {
    $(this).animate({color: "white"}, 400);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({color: "black"}, 400);
})
})
</script>
```

Comment: Is this the full source? Be sure to include ```jQuery``` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Get some semi-colons!

```
$(function() {
$("a").hover(
function() {
    $(this).animate({color: "white"}, 400);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({color: "black"}, 400);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the 'cancelDefault' property to false. http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Comment: How to use it? Edit the main file?

Comment: Set the preferences when you create the tooltip: `$(".trigger").tooltip({ cancelDefault: true });`